# Collision between Rect and another unknown Rect

Tags: python, pygame, collision, rect

I was wondering if it was possible to find out if a Rect is colliding with another Rect. The problem is that I do not know what/where that other Rect is.

1. I have a Rect which moves around (of which I know where it is).
2. I have many other Rects on the same "map".
3. I dont want to make a list of all Rects on the map and then try collideRect with each and every one of them.

Does anyone have an idea under these circumstances for a function that takes a Rect and returns a list of all other Rects with which it collides? (Without using the collideRect function for all existing Rects?)

Can I somehow "scan" only the area of the first Rect and if there is another Rect in the same "spot" I return the other Rect?

I have come up with nothing so far...

Comment: So you basically want to check if a `Rect` collides with another `Rect` without checking they collide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, you will need to check to see if the Rect collides with any other Rect. With that in mind, there are some ways to speed things up, basically relying on grouping Rects.

For example, assuming these Rects are objects in the level that don't move around, you could sort them by the X-coordinate, and remember the maximum width. When you want to run collision detection, start at the main Rect's left side minus the maximum width, and loop through until the Rect's right side. Any Rects outside of that range do not have the ability to collide, and so do not need to be checked.

Alternately, you could divide the level into, say, 16 squares, and give each square a list of all Rects within the square. Then, just decide which square the main Rect is in, and just compare with the Rects in there. (With logic for overlaps, of course.)

There's a large number of ways to do this.

Comment: but how do I handle moving Rects? like the change their x/y constant a lot,   I cannot resort the list all the time. I guess that the division of the level would be one idea to go with, ill see how to figure it out

Comment: Move the Rects, then resort/recategorize them? Unless they're moving around a lot, they aren't going to get too much out of order over a few frames, so you could add in a maximum movement distance, and only redo the sorting once every N frames.